# SQL Query invalid object name issues when using variable

Tags: sql

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'events'.

select count(distinct(games)) from events

Comment: Where is the query? What are you expecting? Tag your dbms.

Comment: This post requires more debugging details and a full description of what you're trying to do and how are you attempting to doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is about that the `events` table cannot be found. So, please ensure that:

- this is the table name
- you have access to this table

It will be better to add the schema. For example, `sales.events`. It is possible that the table is not in your user default schema.